# Using MPI in a multithreaded application

Tags: multithreading, mpi

I am trying to use MPI in a multithreaded application. In the main thread, I initialize the MPI environment and create a Manager object. The Manager object starts two additional threads, one for receiving objects, and a GUI thread. Whenever the user clicks on a Send button, an object is supposed to be sent to the corresponding Rank. Sometimes ths operation succeeds, but there are situations when I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
      at MPI.Unsafe.MPI_Recv(IntPtr buf, Int32 count, Int32 datatype, Int32 source, Int32 tag, Int32 comm, MPI_Status& status)
      at MPI.Communicator.Receive[T](Int32 source, Int32 tag, T& value, CompletedStatus& status)
      at MPI.Communicator.Receive[T](Int32 source, Int32 tag, T& value)
      at MPI.Communicator.Receive[T](Int32 source, Int32 tag)
```

Code:

```
public Manager(String managerID)
{
        //other actions...
        (new Thread(new ThreadStart(startGUIThread))).Start();
        ReceiverThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MachineReceiver));
        ReceiverThread.Start();
}
public void MachineReceiver()
{
        while (IsRunning)
        {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("initiated");
            Data data = Communicator.world.Receive<Data>(source, 100);
            System.Console.Out.Write("Received");
        }
}
```

Comment: for better text formatting: please put two spaces at the end of each line where a new line should follow. Your error message will then look more readable

Comment: Please post additional code - especially the places where you make the MPI related calls.
Also, did you try running this in `gdb` (or similar)?

Comment: What level of threading does your MPI implementation support? The low-level `MPI_Thread_init` returns the level, also one can use `MPI_Query_thread`. Check with your MPI wrapper documentation on how to obtain it. If the provided level is not `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` or `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`, then you **should not** make MPI calls from different thread than the one that called `MPI_Init_thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize MPI with MPI_Init()? If so, that is wrong for a multithreaded program. You need to use MPI_Init_thread() instead. See http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-20-html/node165.htm

Comment: I initialized the MPI environment like so:                         using (new MPI.Environment(ref args, Threading.Multiple))

Comment: Presumably that's some MPI wrapper; then you need to check how that wrapper initializes MPI.

Comment: @user1045747: Check also that the MPI library is built with multi-thread support.  What are the MPI library and wrapper that you are using?

Comment: I figured it out: MS MPI supports up to and including MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED; therefore it does support multiple threads making mpi calls at the same time. Thank you!